# How to get the values of a column in data table in C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, datatables

I have a data table with structure somewhat like this,

```
Week_Number  Col_A  Col_B  Col_C  Col_D  Col_E
----------------------------------------------
    1         10     20     30     40     50
    2         20     30     40     50     60
    3         30     40     50     60     70
    4         40     50     60     70     80
    5         50     60     70     80     90
```

And this is my code in c# to return the values of a data table.

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    foreach (DataColumn dc in dr.Table.Columns)
    {
        lst.Add(dr[dc].ToString());
    }
 }
```

But it returns the values row-wise (e.g., Row[0] - 1,10,20,30,40,50, Row[1],..) whereas I want to get values for column-wise (e.g., Col[0] - 1,2,3,4,5, Col[1],...)

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change order of your loops, your outer loop should be on `Columns` and inner loop should be on rows like:

```
foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
{
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        lst.Add(dr[dc].ToString());
    }
}
```

You will end up with a single list, with all values from first column and then second and onward.

Comment: @Arpita, it should work, make sure your `DataTable` has values, and there are no `null` values for any cell, Are you getting any exception ?

Comment: No. The result is just blank.

Answer (score 0):

You actually want the data from the columns *inside* the DataRow object:

```
dr.field<int>("Week_Number");
dr["Week_Number"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get the value of single Column as below:

```cs
var valueOfColumn = dtTable.Rows[rowIndex][ColumnIndex];
```

if you want all columns you can do that by loop:

```cs
foreach (DataRow dtRow in dtTable.Rows)
{
    foreach(DataColumn dc in dtTable.Columns)
    {
      var field1 = dtRow[dc].ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to get all columns but this didn't work either.